# How to scroll to top of page with JavaScript/jQuery on refresh and exclude specific term?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently using this script:

```
window.onbeforeunload=function(){window.scrollTo(0,0);}
```

**Edited:** I want to scroll the page to the top when triggering a page refresh.
The problem is that the script is also working/executing when a user clicks on an `a href` element which is a download link from a subdomain that represent a downloadserver (that is hosted on external host) - let's say downloadserver.mydomain.com

```
<a href="xxx.mydomain.com/filetodownload.extension">
```

Is it possible to exclude the triggering when user click on such link with that specific subdomain?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the purpose of this? Do you just want to to be scrolled to the top after the page refresh?

Comment: yes, just when refreshing

Comment: While refreshing, or after the refresh? The later would be easier.

Comment: could you provide both? while and after. I think after can be fine.

Comment: On a page load your script stops dead. Why are you expecting a transition to be visible at all if you do not delay the loading to subsequent frames? (allowing the scroll to complete)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know that it's a proper answer but works for you

1.Just have a global variable say `isRefreshed`.

```
var isRefreshed = true;
```

2.Have a anchor click listener

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(){
  if($(this).attr('href') !== "your current page url"){
     isRefreshed = false; //i.e clicked another url
  }
});
```

3.And finally your `scroller`

```
window.onbeforeunload=function(){
   if(isRefreshed) window.scrollTo(0,0); //calls only when refreshed
}
```

This is a simple hack. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
 window.onbeforeunload=function(){
  if (window.location.href.indexOf('xxx.mydomain.com') >= 0)
     window.scrollTo(0,0);
 }
```

Comment: not working. the script "window.scrollTo(0,0);" is not executing at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want your page to always be scrolled to the top after the page is refreshed, you could just run this code when the page's document is ready:

```
window.scrollTo(0,0);
```

So run it from a `script` tag before the `body` closes, or wait for the document to be ready, [with](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) or [without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery).